# How to cleanup h2 db after each junit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, h2

I am making junit tests which adds some users before each test case. The code is:

```
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        saveUser();
        saveEntry();
    }
    
    @Test
    void saveUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(null);
        user.setUsername("John");
        user.setEmail("john@foo.com");
        user.setPassword("password");
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Test
    void saveEntry() {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        entry.setText("test text");
        entry.setUserId(1L);
        entryService.saveEntry(entry);
    }
```

As you see I am using the methods that I have in my service layer to create entries and users. If I run the tests one by one there is no problem. But when I run all tests then db is not returning 1 item and returning multiple items so exception occurs.

I need to cleanup h2 db after each test with maybe @AfterEach annotation but I do not have and delete method in my code to invoke. How can I cleanup the H2 db ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @J Asgarov answer which is correct providing you use `spring-boot` if you want to perform some actions before and after each test (more specifically before `@Before` and after `@After` methods) you can use `@Sql` annotation to execute specific `sql` script for example from test resources.

```
@Sql("init.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "clean.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class TestClass
}
```

It might be handy for `sequences`, since they don't care of rollback.

Regarding `@Transactional` mentioned by @Mark Bramnik be careful, because the transaction spans for entire test method, so you cannot verify correctness of the transaction boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned spring and it looks like you're testing DAO layer, so I assume the tests are running with SpringExtension/SpringRunner if you're on junit 4.

In this case,

Have you tried to use `@Transactional` on the test method? Or alternatively if all the test methods are "transactional" you can place it once on a test class.

This works as follows:

If everything is configured correctly spring will open a transaction before the test starts, and will rollback that transaction after the test ends.

The rollback is supposed to clean the inserted data automatically.

Quick googling revealed [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/write-transactional-unit-tests-spring/), surely there are many others

Answer (score 0):

`@DataJpaTest` annotating the test class will rollback every test by default

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database

Comment: Did you mean `@DataJpaTest`? I can't find `@JpaDataTest`. Anyway, neither of those is mentioned in the article you linked, at least as of today.

Comment: yes, u r right `@DataJpaTest` is what i mean, updated the answer